# Beautifulsoup giving wrong information

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I parse the below soup and surprisingly, it give me wrong text as below:

`NYSE:BAC (USD)`

`FQ1 2022FQ2 2022FQ3 2022FQ4 2022FY 2022FQ1 2023`

The code I use is `print(containers[0].text)`

and `print(containers[0])` shown below.

I thought it should give me:

`NYSE:BAC (USD)`

`FQ1 2022 FQ2 2022 FQ3 2022 FQ4 2022 FY 2022 FY 2022 FY1 2023`

Can you please help?

```html
<tr class="cColHeaderBG">
    <th align="left" class="cColHeaderBG" scope="col" style="width:1%;">
                                                    NYSE:BAC (USD)
                                                    
        <span style="float: right">
            <img height="1px" src="/CIQDotNet/Images/shim.gif" width="120px"/>
        </span>
    </th>
    <th align="right" class="cColHeaderBG" scope="col" style="width:14.16667%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <div onclick="RowHighlightFunctionality.ToggleColumn(this.parentNode);" style="width:100%;">FQ1 2022</div>
    </th>
    <th align="right" class="cColHeaderBG" scope="col" style="width:14.16667%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <div onclick="RowHighlightFunctionality.ToggleColumn(this.parentNode);" style="width:100%;">FQ2 2022</div>
    </th>
    <th align="right" class="cColHeaderBG" scope="col" style="width:14.16667%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <div onclick="RowHighlightFunctionality.ToggleColumn(this.parentNode);" style="width:100%;">FQ3 2022</div>
    </th>
    <th align="right" class="cColHeaderBG" scope="col" style="width:14.16667%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <div onclick="RowHighlightFunctionality.ToggleColumn(this.parentNode);" style="width:100%;">FQ4 2022</div>
    </th>
    <th align="right" class="cColHeaderBG" scope="col" style="width:14.16667%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <div onclick="RowHighlightFunctionality.ToggleColumn(this.parentNode);" style="width:100%;">FY 2022</div>
    </th>
    <th align="right" class="cColHeaderBG" scope="col" style="width:14.16667%;white-space:nowrap;">
        <div onclick="RowHighlightFunctionality.ToggleColumn(this.parentNode);" style="width:100%;">FQ1 2023</div>
    </th>
</tr>
```

Container is obtained from:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(bot.page_source, 'lxml')
containers = soup.find_all('div', {'id' : '_TradingItemNav_ctl01_rootrepeater_DisplaySection1_0'})
```

Comment: Show us the definition of `containers`.

Comment: The spacing between "FQ1 2022" and "FQ2 2022" (for example) comes entirely from the fact that the two items are in different table cells; there is no actual whitespace character between them.  If you want the items separated, you need to dig down a little deeper than `containers[0]`, to the level where the separate `<th>` elements are.

Comment: I make it longer then it turn correct value.``` for i in containers[0]:
    true_value.append(i.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

loop inside containers[0] to get the exact value

```
for i in containers[0]:
    print(i.text)
```